# Header causing unnecessary scrollbar.

Tags: html, css

I have two main `div`. One is `#header` for menu, and one is `#container` for the content. I want that `#container` to reach the bottom of the page, whether is filled with content or not.
The problem is that adding `height:100%;` to `body`, `html` and `#container` causes the additional white space and **scrollbar**, which i do not want when not necessary.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='container'></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{

    margin:0;
}

body,html {height:100%;}

#header {

    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}

#container {

    width:600px;
    background-color:gray;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

> **JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ymBnw/**

Comment: Your `#container` can't have its height set to a 100% if on top of it you have the `#header` consuming `70px`.

Comment: Add the colour to the body instead and remove the height of the container.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Cannot, since the container width is not 100%. It would have totally different outcome. Check the fiddle to see where's the problem.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that... (the fiddle body is less than 600px on my screen).

Comment: @BikerJohn I've just updated my answer, could give it a try please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you play with the `padding` and the `margin` of the `#container`, and position the `#header` absolutely, you can achieve this. I'm not taking into consideration the `width`, which you can set as you like.

```
html, 
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 10;
}

#container {    
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: -70px auto -70px auto;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

#content
{
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ymBnw/15/

**EDIT**

I've made a mistake setting the `padding`, which needs to be (obviously) the double of the `margin` (140px instead of 70px). Code fixed.

**EDIT 2**

Not happy again. The previous edit made the scrollbars to come back. The new solution proposed adds a new `div` within the `#container`.

Comment: @HashemQolami I've fixed and posted an edit. Thanks for spotting the mistake.

Comment: My pleasure, but it increases the height of the page. check the scrollbar.

Comment: I don't understand why the OP didn't give himself a second thought. ignored my solution completely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would do that. Because you've given the `#container` 100% height, that is relative to the body. So you've given the `#container` the same height as the body. On top of that, you've got the `#header` height. So your total content is now 100% + 70px (header).

The way around this would be to set no height on the `#container` and have the grey background colour on the body.

You could also try:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  top: -70px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

#header { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10; }
```

Or you could try:

```
  #container {
      margin-top: -70px;
      padding-top: 70px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
```

I'm not a fan of the second method. You could also do this with absolute positioning and a 70px padding on the top of the container.

Comment: Yes, but setting a background color is not a solution since the container does not fill the whole area but only a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a position:absolute on the container div.

Code:

```
#container {
    width:600px;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:70px;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-300px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymBnw/6/)

Comment: It would save a lot of hassle to position the container centered (as the OP wants) if you just position absolutely the header instead.

Comment: I agree with @MelanciaUk especially as that way round you wouldn't have to worry about z-index

Answer (score 1):

You should use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` to fix the `background-color` issue.

Here is a working solution:

**CSS**

```
#header {
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

#container {
    width:600px;
    background-color:gray;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: -70px;
    padding-top: 70px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/ymBnw/11/)**

**[JSFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/ymBnw/12/)**

As an alternative solution, instead of `box-sizing`, you can use `::before` pseudo-element as the following:

```
#container {
    width:600px;
    background-color:gray;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: -70px;
}

#container:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #3](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/ymBnw/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#container {

width:100%;
background-color:gray;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}



#header {
height:70px;
width:100%;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymBnw/9/)

Comment: There's still a scrollbar in your fiddle. This doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the height of the `container` to be 100% but you're then setting the `header` height to be 70px. This will ultimately lead to your full body being 100% of the browser window + 70px.

That's why you will be getting a scrollbar, because 100% + 70px results in overflow.

**Edit:**

As others have suggested, you could use an absolutely positioned header, with a padded container. You would obviously lose flow in this scenario though. When it comes to specifying heights in HTML, there are always trade-offs...

Comment: Is it possible then to appy some kind of negative margin for header?

Comment: @BikerJohn a negative margin would not help you here. The key is resolving the mix of percentage heights with explicit heights. (px vs %)

Answer (score 0):

Using the new flexbox layout, all you have to do is to add these CSS properties to the body.

```
body {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

This sets the layout to flexbox and specifies that the direct children of the body element should be aligned top to bottom. For a more thorough guide to flexbox, have a look at this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Note that the flexbox layout is currently a candidate recommendation and older browsers are not going to support it. Current Webkit based browsers still need the -webkit vendor prefix.